# How to locate maximum value and position in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, key-value-coding

I need to search a mutable array for the maximum value and return its position as well as value. I'd only like to iterate through the array once and I'm not sure if that's possible

an example of what I'm trying to accomplish can be demonstrated below

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
        [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(arc4random()%200)]];

    NSObject *max = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"];
```

the `max` object only seems to contain the value (and not the position). this can be demonstrated through the debugger with `print-object max`

Any advice out there?

Comment: The `max` object doesn't have the position because there can be more than one occurrence of the value in your array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `valueForKeyPath:@"@max.self"` is great, but only if you want the maximum value.

To know both index and value in one iteration, I'd use `enumerateWithBlock:`

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:(arc4random()%200)]];

__block NSUInteger maxIndex;
__block NSNumber* maxValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSNumber* newValue = obj;
    if ([newValue isGreaterThan:maxValue]) {
        maxValue = newValue;
        maxIndex = idx;
    }
}];
```

Quite more code, but you're iterating only once in the array.

Comment: great more reading for me (what is a block???) but it works... You also indirectly solved a second problem, so thanks

Comment: A block is a closure, also available in other programming languages. As you said, more reading! Official documentation : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

If you're not worried about the possibility of there being more than one identical maximum value in the array, you can use `-indexOfObject:` to get the index. It will return the first occurrence of the object in the array.

```
NSUInteger index = [array indexOfObject:max];
```

Comment: That what I'm trying to avoid: a second iteration through my array. My example has 20 objects, my real code has much more and is being reprocessed regularly

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to insert objects at the end of the array? Maybe you should consider inserting objects in a way that keeps your array sorted, or even think about using a different data structure that will allow for easy finding of maximum value (max-heap perhaps?).

Comment: @gcamp, yup sorry. I missed that reading the first time through.

Answer (score 2):

I hope, following solution will help you to identify maximum value from array.

```
int max = [[numberArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];    
NSLog(@"Highest number: %i",max);
```

Please let me know if any issue.

Comment: @iPatel, Please don't edit the answer if you did not find any other best alternative solution. you have added few space in prefix.b Please don't do these things

Comment: @iPatel just corrected the formatting. Nothing wrong in that.

Comment: There are difference between answering and editing. If u have a different solution, u should put a separate answer. But formatting edition is acceptable, and fine for editting.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find correct way to deal with collections and KVC 
Its nice Post by Matt
http://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/